# CSS: Header cut off in Chrome using Materialize framework

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the materialize framework to construct a web-app.

My website looks great in Firefox, but in Google chrome (PC/mobile versions) the text in the header bar is cut off by 50%, like such:

[image]

Here is the code for that image snippet:

```html
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

<header>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-2">
        <div class="valign-wrapper">
            <a id="app_page_title" href="#" class="brand-logo center" style="font-weight: 200;">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <?php echo($admin_btn) ?>
            <?php echo($stats_btn) ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
 </header>
```

Run the code snippet to see what I mean.

Just wondering how to position it correctly (vertically centered) as it is in firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own CSS, But you've to make the rules `!important` to make it apply on the header. This will work same on all browsers.

Look at the snippet below:

```css
.brand-logo {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

<header>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-2">
        <div class="valign-wrapper">
            <a id="app_page_title" href="#" class="brand-logo center" style="font-weight: 200;">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <?php echo($admin_btn) ?>
            <?php echo($stats_btn) ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
 </header>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks pal, perfect answer.

Comment: @Vranvs It's my pleasure!